# How can I wrap long text labels in highchart nested groups

Tags: charts, highcharts, grouping, axis-labels

i want to display text in wrap format in high chart nested group

If d.name is too long I'd like it to fill several lines instead of one.

```
[http://jsfiddle.net/vijay6512/5j9LLyxk/embedded/result/]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set `useHTML` flag as true and then set `word-break:break-all` in the css.

CSS

```
.highcharts-xaxis-labels {
    word-break: break-all;
}
```

HC

```
labels:{
                maxStaggerLines: 1,
                useHTML:true,

},
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/5j9LLyxk/3/